# How to replace between two flank string in php

Tags: php

hey guys I'm trying to replace between two flank string specifically

for example, I have a string that looks like this: `(color=red)`
so i want replace this string `(color=` with `<span style="color:`
and then the end of the flank string `)` with `">`

so the result must be

> `<span style="color:red">`

more like a BBCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular Expressions will help you

```php
$input = '(color=red)';
$output = preg_replace('/\((\w+)=(\w+)\)/', '<span style="$1:$2">', $input);
```